# Mysql Get Column Name after Case Max

Tags: mysql, identity

i have this scenario with this query that trasform multiple rows key/values in a columns.

```
SELECT
  t1.*, t2.*, u.name, u.email, u.username, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.datakey = 'latitude' THEN t2.data END) AS latitude,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.datakey = 'longitude' THEN t2.data END)AS longitude
FROM `#_social_fields_data` AS t1 
INNER JOIN `#_social_fields_data` AS t2 ON t1.uid  = t2.uid
LEFT JOIN `f9leh_users` AS u ON t1.uid = u.id
GROUP BY t1.uid
```

and i need to add a where clause to call the latitude value
but adding clause for example

```
where latitude > 0
```

and after i need to call the colum to replace the new a.lat with latitude column name

```
 $distance_col_expression = "(((acos(sin((".$post['socialmembers']['location_lat']."*pi()/180)) *
                            sin((a.lat * pi()/180))+cos((".$post['socialmembers']['location_lat']." * pi()/180)) *
                            cos((a.lat * pi()/180)) * cos(((".$post['socialmembers']['location_lng']."- a.lng)
                            *pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) 
                            ";
                        $query .= ' AND '.$distance_col_expression .' <= '.$post['socialmembers']['search_radius'];
```

it not work. Says invalid column name. I have tried with other names but seems that this name generated is temporary.

Please can suggest me, How can i do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to either use a subquery or place that latitude code in a having clause.

Comment: hI @blueefeet , please can you show me some example. I am not a query expert and i have no idea of how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Look in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html for subqueries. It's not too difficult, it's essentially putting a query inside parenthesis and using the result as criteria for the nesting query.

Comment: Why is there a self-join to `#_social_fields_data` table?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the useful suggestion.

Now the query work as in this way:

```
select DISTINCT t3.uid,latitude,longitude
from (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
  t2.*, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.datakey = 'latitude' THEN t2.data END) AS latitude,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.datakey = 'longitude' THEN t2.data END)AS longitude
FROM `#_social_fields_data` AS t1 
INNER JOIN `#_social_fields_data` AS t2 ON t1.uid  = t2.uid
GROUP BY t1.uid
     ) as t3
WHERE latitude > 0
```

Thanks, as suggested i have optimized the query removing self_join:

```
select DISTINCT t2.uid,latitude,longitude
from (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
  t1.*, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t1.datakey = 'latitude' THEN t1.data END) AS latitude,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t1.datakey = 'longitude' THEN t1.data END)AS longitude
FROM `#_social_fields_data` AS t1 
GROUP BY t1.uid
     ) as t2
WHERE latitude > 0
```